# Want to understand that what domReady.done, domReady.timer means?

Tags: jquery, javascript, javascript-framework, unobtrusive-javascript

I found this example in a JavaScript book

```
// Checks to see if the DOM is ready for navigation
function isDOMReady() {
    // If we already figured out that the page is ready, ignore

    if (domReady.done) return false;
    // Check to see if a number of functions and elements are
    // able to be accessed
    if (document && document.getElementsByTagName && document.getElementById && document.body) {
        // If they're ready, we can stop checking
        clearInterval(domReady.timer);
        domReady.timer = null;
        // Execute all the functions that were waiting
        for (var i = 0; i < domReady.ready.length; i++)
        domReady.ready[i]();
        // Remember that we're now done
        domReady.ready = null;
        domReady.done = true;
    }
}

// calling the domReady function
domReady(function () {
    alert("The DOM is loaded!");
    tag("h1")[0].style.border = "4px solid black";
});
```

Want to understand that what `domReady.done`, `domReady.timer` means?

Comment: We can't because they are not included in the code you provide here. Alltogether waiting for the DOM is a simple `setInterval` that gets cleared when the dom-functions are accessable und thus the dom is ready. `domReady.timer` is the id of the according interval, and `domReady.done` is the flag that indicates whether the dom is ready or not.

Comment: Its just a flag which will indicate whether the dom is ready. but it is a customized javascript function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`domReady.done` is a flag that will be set to true as soon as the DOM is ready. `domReady.timer` is the reference / handle to an interval started with `window.setInterval` so that it can be cleared with `window.clearInterval()` as soon as the DOM is ready because there is no need to check any longer.